# ASP.NET ScriptManager not including the right version of MicrosoftAjax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

My ScriptManager for some reason includes an old version of MicrosoftAjaxWebForms and all the other MicrosoftAjax libs. It does not matter if I use EnableCDN or not. ScriptResource.axd provides the old version from CodePlex instead of the new one.
If I enable CDN it still gets it from ScriptResource.axd instead of the CND. On my coworkers PC it works fine. We share the project and have basically the same project settings and installation.
ASP.NET 4.5 is installed. And the System.Web.Extension libs from 4.0 are there and referenced in the project.

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Have you tried using Nuget to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, everything is up-to-date.